# JavaScript Class getter/setter and v-model in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

I created a Form class where i set up some getters and setter for every filed the form could have.

In the getters and setters i am writing and accessing the Vuex storage:

The init() function is where i set up g/s.

```
export class Form {

    /**
     * @param data
     */
    constructor(data) {

        this.init(data);

        this.errors = new Errors();

    }

    /**
     * initially set up the getters/setters properties for the fields
     * @param data
     */
    init(data) {


        for (const propertyData in data) {

            if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyData) && !Form.isPrototypeOf(propertyData)) {

                Object.defineProperty(Form.prototype, propertyData, {

                    get: function () {

                        return store.state.form[propertyData];

                    },

                    set: function (value) {

                        store.commit('set', {field: propertyData, value: value});
                    },

                });

            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * set the properties , also setup new setters/getters if new props where added
     * @param data
     * @returns Object {Form}
     */
    fill(data) {


        for (let field in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                this[field] = data[field];
            }
        }

        return this;
    }


    reset() {
        store.commit('reset');

        return this;
    }

    data() {

        return store.state.form;
    }
}
```

This works just greate when i have an input and bind form.name for example
it is written in the Vue Storge.

and when i do a console.log on this form.name it show the changes

```
...
        methods: {
            test() {
              console.log(this.form.name);
            },
...
```

What i noticed and that is actually my problem and the Question.

when i do {{form.name}} under the input for example this is not getting updated like it should, and im not sure why?

EDIT:

after the feedback from @Jacob Goh and hacking around for a while with my problem it seems that i have found a solution:

```
init(data) {


    for (let propertyData in data) {

        this[propertyData + '_i'] = data[propertyData];

        if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyData) && !Form.prototype.hasOwnProperty(propertyData)) {

            Object.defineProperty(Form.prototype, propertyData, {

                get: function () {

                    this[propertyData + '_i'] = store.state.form[propertyData];

                    return this[propertyData + '_i'];

                },

                set: function (value) {

                    this[propertyData + '_i'] = value;

                    store.commit('set', {field: propertyData, value: value});
                },

            });

        }

    }

}
```

the variable in the vue and also in the console log seem to update right.
Im not quit sure what is happening tho.

My guess would that i add new propertys to the object with _i so vue think he has to set up a bunch of new watchers.

Hope some one could clarify this.

Comment: May i know why did you do it this way? Things would be a lot easier if you use Vue's  options (data,computed, methods)

Comment: i wanted to have my fields capsuled in a Form class /object or what ever, So i could just simple submit it, and also handle the errors.

Comment: [Every reactive data in Vue has its own getter, setter](https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407). According to https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked , the setter is responsible for notifying the watcher that a change has occured and DOM should be updated. `form.name` has it's own setter that works outside Vue. So it's not reactive and won't update. That's just my 2 cents. I don't know how to make this work without doing something hacky.

Comment: Hmm , now this is a problem, thx for the heads up.

Comment: updated my question with a possible solution